# trie implementation in python , object reference

Tags: trie

im looking at the following implementation of trie in python:

```
tree = {}

def add_to_tree(root, value_string):
    for character in value_string:
        root = root.setdefault(character, {})

def main():
    tree={}
    add_to_tree(tree, 'abc')
    print tree

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

What is not clear to me is:

1. why is it returning `{a:{b:{c:{}}}}` instead of `{a:{},b:{},c:{}}` ?
2. I ran the code through [this](http://pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit) which gives a visualization of it. After iterating though 'a' I get `tree = {'a':{}}, root = {}` then after 'b' I get `tree = {a:{b:{}}}, root={}`. Whats not clear is what variable is holding the reference to `{b:{}}` which gets assigned to `{a:{}}` to change it to `{a:{b:{}}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning root to the newly created dict for every character, change this line:

```
root = root.setdefault(character, {})
```

To becomes:

```
root.setdefault(character, {})
```

This gives the desired output (note that dict are unordered):

```
{'a': {}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}}
```